# OpenCV 2.4.3 build fails on Visual studio 2010, error in gen_java.py

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, build

I have downloaded the source code for OpenCV 2.4 (I think it is 2.4.3), ran Cmake on it and I am producing a VS2010 solution file.

While compiling the solution file produced by cmake, the build fails with an the following error message:

```
2>------ Build started: Project: opencv_java, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  Building Custom Rule C:/temp/opencv-2.4/software/src/modules/java/CMakeLists.txt
2>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\temp\opencv-2.4\software\src\Release\modules\java\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>  Generating core.cpp
2>    File "C:/temp/opencv-2.4/software/src/modules/java/generator/gen_java.py", line 1285
2>      epilogue = "  ".join(c_epilogue) + ("\n        " if c_epilogue else ""), \
                    2>                                                        ^
                    2>  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
                    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
```

Anybody know what is going on here and how to fix the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was the local python installation. I then installed the newer version, Python 2.7, set the relevant paths and tried again, and this time OpenCV compiled fine.

Hope this helps somebody else in a similar situation.